# Implementing Optimistic locking in Hibernate using @Version or LockMode.OPTIMISTIC or both

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I read that we can implement optimistic locking in hibernate using version field using `@Version`. Then on reading about pessimistic locking, I came to know that `org.hibernate.LockMode` class which has some options like `LockMode.OPTIMISTIC` etc which we can specify in `session.load()`.

So my question is do I need to use `LockMode.OPTIMISTIC` also along with `@Version`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  They work together, you can use `@Version` without `LockMode.OPTIMISTIC` but you cannot use `LockMode.OPTIMISTIC` without `@Version`.

With optimistic locking, whenever you modify an entity then the version column of the entity is incremented.  When an entity is saved it ensures that the version column is what it was when the entity was first read and, if not, it throws an `OptimisticLockException` (which typically results in a restart of the transaction).

There could be times when you need to "change" an entity without really changing it.  This tends to be pretty rare.  For example, imagine there a `Foo` object which has a `mode` field and a `Bar` object which has a `volume` field.  If the `mode` is `LOUD` the `volume` can be 0-100.  If the `mode` is `QUIET` the `volume` can only be 0-10.

It's possible with optimistic locking that you can get in a bad state if one user changes the `mode` (from `LOUD` to `QUIET`) at the same time another user changes the `volume` (from 5 to 50).  This is because the first user increments and checks the version column on the `Foo` entity and the second user increments and checks the version column on the `Bar` entity.

One solution for this would be for your `changeVolume` function to obtain a `LockMode.OPTIMISTIC` lock on the `Foo` object.  This tells Hibernate that even though this function doesn't modify the `Foo` object it still needs to increment and check the version field.